# Update file references while looping

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to loop through files in a folder and take data for that files using references, im using below code , but still getting Update Values window popped up at every file in which I have to manually select path of files. How to do this reference automatically

[Salary.Value is name of a cell in files in that folder]

```
Dim myfolder As String
Dim myfile As String
Dim wbk As Workbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "please select a folder"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
myfile = Dir(myfolder)

Do While myfile <> ""
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myfolder & myfile)

' the next line is the one in question
Range("I6").FormulaR1C1 = "='myfile'!Salary.value"

myfile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

A browse window named update values is popping up

[image]

Comment: in addition to tdi's answer you should fully qualify `Range("I6")` with a workbook/worksheet.  Oherwise it will be on the Activesheet, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

'MyFile' is a variable name. But how you use it, it is considered as name of the workbook.
Try

```
Range("I6").FormulaR1C1 = "='" + MyFile + "'!Salary.value"
```

instead